# Doubts about data binding in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS by doing my first app with it. As far as now, everything was working ok and I'm pretty excited :)

But now I have a console.log that is totally confusing me, and I'm start thinking I've completely missed something.

I have a simple tag bound to a controller:

```
<h2 ng-controller='HeaderController' ng-show='data.actualSection > 0'>
    {{titleForSection()}}
</h2>
```

The controller is very simple:

```
    uxctModule.controller ('HeaderController', function ($scope, ModelData){
    $scope.data = ModelData;

    $scope.titleForSection = function () {
        console.log ("RETURNING IT");
        return ("I SHOULD RETURN YOU SOMETHING");
    }
});
```

What's really confusing me is that I've noticed that every time something is changing in the model, the function is triggered.
How can the controller be executing the function constantly without a $watch in it?

Comment: what is the purpose of `titleForSection()` in your template? In general should bind function calls to buttons, etc. but not put them directly in templates.

Comment: @Sebastian the reason is that the label is going to be dynamic, and the controller should provide the right label for it

Comment: I think what he is saying is don't bind the function to the template. Call the function in the controller and assign the output to a variable in the scope which would be used in the template. Angular works by dirty-checking the scopes, so it will call your function over and over again...

Comment: @Sebastian you should post it as the answer because my wrong approach was the reason of the function repeating over and over again. Thank you

Comment: @aet you should post it as the answer because my wrong approach was the reason of the function repeating over and over again. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data binding in angular is done via a digest loop, which means that angular loops over and over again checking for changes, and in the case of a function that is bound to the function must be evaluated looking for changes.

This is the reason it is generally a bad idea to bind your UI to the result of a function. 
Instead you should do something like this:

Markup:

```
<h2 ng-controller='HeaderController' ng-show='data.actualSection > 0'>
    {{sectionTitle}}
</h2>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.sectionTitle = 'I SHOULD RETURN YOU SOMETHING';
//and update it dynamically
$scope.funcToUpdateTitle = function(newTitle){
    $scope.sectionTitle = newTitle;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually in angularJS all functions related to view will be called as and when a digest cycle is called in that way since you have called `titleForSection()` in your HTML so when where an event occurs in the HTML, causes the function to be executed.

Hope it helps!